# I want to read particular string from a text file and store them in Excel sheets

Tags: java, string, excel, poi-hssf

My Text file Contains line like this

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **Remedy Application Service**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **Remedy Application Service**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **ibsdr**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **Vinay.k@in.uni.com**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **Vinay.k@in.uni.com**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **wsdl**

FLTR   TID: 0000003756 RPC ID: 0000108159 USER: **stefan.hummel@uni.com**

I want to store highlighted words in Excel sheets in columns wise and i want to store only unique user names.. like:

**Column1**....**Column2**

**S.NO**...........**UserName**

**1**..................**Remedy Application Service**

**2**..................**ibsdr**

**3**..................**Vinay.k@in.uni.com**

**4**..................**wsdl**

**5**..................**stefan.hummel@uni.com**

This is what I have tried

```
public class User {

    static HSSFWorkbook hwb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    static HSSFSheet sheet = hwb.createSheet("new sheet");
    static HSSFRow rowhead = sheet.createRow((short) 0);
    static HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short) 1);
    static int count = 1;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        try {
            rowhead.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("SNo");
            rowhead.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("USER NAME");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("filter.log"));
            String str = null;
            String user = null;
            while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (str.contains("FLTR")) {
                    user = str.substring(48, 75); // This is to get user names
                    count++;
                    store(user, count);
                }
            }
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("D:/Excel.xls");
            hwb.write(fileOut);
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private static void store(String user, int count) {
        row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(count);
        row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(user);
    }
}
```

OUTPUT

S.NO.......UserName

17963......Remedy Application Service

in this whenever I execute this program only first value is getting stored rather all values stores.. and I want to store only **UNIQUE user names** in this Excel sheet..

please help me , thanks in advance

Comment: Please show the output you get.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "unique user names"?

Comment: @BetaRide, please see output and unique user names means if one user name is repeated then it should store only once in excel sheet

Comment: A smallish flaw: your `count` variable will commence at 2 due to the initialisation to 1 and the increment before the use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For Unique Names you can Use `ArrayList<String>` add whenever new UserName appears add and before that check whether user exist in arrayList or not *(by the Use of* `contains("UName")`*)*  and than proceed.
- Use `String username=line.substring(line.lastindexOf(":")).trim();` or You can use `line.split(":")[1].trim();`

*For Excel row creation you can use loop.*

```
int i=0;
while((str=br.readLine())!=null){
row = sheet.createRow((short) i);
cell = row.createCell(i);
cell.setCellValue("UserName");//Set UserName after getting it from 'str'
i++;
}
```

Comment: @ Task.... +2 for you.. Good Work thanks.. i am beginner in programming.. it helped me more

Comment: I would not suggest using a `List` as the complexity of the lookup is much higher than for the same operation on, for example, `HashSet`.

Comment: @TAsk... which one should prefer here ?? ArrayList or HashSet

Comment: Agree with Eric Tobias you should Use HashSet for this as well as it won't allow duplicate.But as you are adding elements one by one you have to chech whether username exist or not so that I suggested ArrayList

Comment: @TAsk...i appreciate all efforts done by each..i don have enough reputation to upvote..thumbs up..Once i get more reputation i upvote for your answers, at this point of time i can only accept one answer. but for me all answers are needed n welcome..

Comment: Yes I understand not a big deal I am happy that it helped and My answer will be helpful in future for others :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, I am not an expert and have never tried this myself nor can I at the moment. From looking at your code I can spot a few design flaws that might be the reason for your problem.

You only ever declare one row:

```
static HSSFRow row= sheet.createRow((short)1);
```

This means that in your `store` method, the same row's cells will be written again and again. What you are missing is the logic to create a new row if a unique name is encountered. For this task, may I suggest using a `Set` preferably one operating on hashes for the benefit of low lookup time, and storing all unique names in there? That way you can use a simply `contains` query.

Furthermore, your `count`variable is off and starts counting at 2, not at one. Initialise it to 0 or increment it after its use.

Some pseudocode:

```
private HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<>();
// More fields here.

// Now start in your if clause:
if(str.contains("FLTR" && !names.contains(str.substring(48))
{
    store(user, count);
    count++;
    names.add(str.substring(48));
}

// More of your code.

private static void store(String user, int count)
{
    // Create new row
    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow((short)rowCount);
    rowCount++;


    row.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(count);
    row.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue(user);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. I added some pseudocode. While some things are missing, you might want to have a look at it.

Comment: @Eric.. this really helpful.. thanks +2 for your effort

Comment: Glad I could help. If this was the answer to your question, I'd appreciate if you could accept it. (You can only accept one answer though you can upvote all if you want.)

Comment: @Eric.. I didnt know this since i joined yesterday..and i appreciate all efforts done by each..i don have enough reputation to upvote..

Comment: Then you should accept the answer which helped you most and come back later! And be sure to register! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you two improvements which will make it easier to solve your issue.

1) Do not attempt to write into Excel sheet using Java, its slightly complicated. Instead you can write into a CSV file. You can externally open this CSV file and save as Excel.

2) The below line might cause trimming of the user names:

```
 user=str.substring(48,75);   // This is to get user names
```

Instead you can use

```
user=str.substring(48);   // This is to get user names
```

So, writing a CSV doesn't need Excel libraries and it can be opened in an excel workbook as well. :)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. and later i want to create one more column and store some confidential information in that.. whenever i read log file and encounter these user names, replace user names with  confidential information stored in excel sheet 3 rd column..

Comment: Never ever, and I mean ever, store confidential information in an excel file in plain text!

Answer (score 0):

public class UniqueUSER
{

static HSSFWorkbook hwb=new HSSFWorkbook();

static HSSFSheet sheet =  hwb.createSheet("new sheet");

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException

{

HSSFRow row;

HashSet names = new HashSet<>();

BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("simle.log"));

PrintStream out=new PrintStream("D:/Excel.xls");

String str=null;

int count=0;

while((str=br.readLine())!=null)
{

if(str.contains("FLTR"))

{

String user=str.substring(97, 135);

count++;

names.add(user);

HSSFRow row1=   sheet.createRow((short)count);

row1.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("names");

}

}

Iterator itr=names.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{

```
out.println(itr.next());
```

}

}

}

Comment: @user:3711467.. this one i used concept from all above Guys Eric,Task and dharam... just wrote complete one for you.. ope this should store value.. thanks to Eric,Task n Dharam

Comment: this is directly storing values into excel sheet.. does it not require columns to create and then store??

Comment: @all... can some one tell me that is it going to store values correctly in excel sheet n will be able to read values in columns successfully